# Intel Centrino Wimax 6250 - Constant Slow and Dropped signal (Ubuntu 13.10)

Tags: wireless, drivers, intel-wireless

I've been surfing the forums for a while now, and I have hit a brick wall. I have a Sony Viao computer with the above mentioned Wireless Adapter. It constantly slows to speeds of under 20 kb/sec, goes back and forth, or sometimes (when I'm lucky) hits speeds exceeding 500 kb/s, which should be constant if I'm not correct :S
I downloaded the latest firmware, and unpacked the archive to /lib/firmware as Every attempt to find the drivers sends me to this site, http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi#Download, but I can only find firmware here. What is the next step that I'm missing?
 Is this even a driver issue, or is there something else wrong.
I'm lost in Ubuntu and I'm a noob. Help!

PS> I just noticed another detail. In the readme file for the firmware it reads:
"2. INSTALLATION

The iwlagn driver will look for the file iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode using the
kernel's firmware_class infrastructure. More information can be found under
Documentation/firmware_class in kernel source. In order to function
correctly, you need to have this support enabled in your kernel.  When
you configure the kernel, you can find this option in the following
location:

```
    Device Drivers ->
            Generic Driver Options ->
                    Userspace firmware loading support
```

You can determine if your kernel currently has firmware loader support
by looking for the CONFIG_FW_LOADER definition on your kernel's
.config."

I just realized that I have no idea what this means, how to find this config file or if it is relevant to my problem. Help!

PSS>When I try to run the intel auto detect/install function on firefox instead, here: http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/wireless, it comes back with an error saying,

The Intel Driver Update Utility installation failed.

Possible web browser compatiblity, firewall, or installation issue detected.

Select OK to troubleshoot issue

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the infamous trick for these devices. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.